# My recursive RISCV assembly code returns the same value as the input

Tags: c, recursion, assembly, riscv

My task: Write an assembly program that uses recursion to add the number 42 to a sum  times, where  is given by the input.

The problem I encountered is that every time I input a value, the same value comes back without returning the recursive solution. For example, I input 5, the output is 5.

Here is my assembly code:

```
.text
    .globl meaning_of_life
    .type meaning_of_life, @function
meaning_of_life:
    addi sp, sp, -16     # Allocate stack space for this frame
    sd ra, 8(sp)         # Save the return address
    sd a0, 0(sp)         # Save the original value of n

    li t0, 42            # Load 42 into temporary register t0
    beqz a0, base_case   # If n is 0, jump to base_case

    addi a0, a0, -1      # Decrement n
    call meaning_of_life # Recursive call

    add a0, a0, t0       # Add 42 to the result of the recursion

    ld ra, 8(sp)         # Restore the return address
    ld a0, 0(sp)         # Optionally restore original n, if needed for other logic
    addi sp, sp, 16      # Deallocate stack space
    ret                  # Return to the caller

base_case:
    li a0, 0             # Base case: the sum is 0
    ld ra, 8(sp)         # Restore the return address
    addi sp, sp, 16      # Deallocate stack space
    ret                  # Return to the caller
```

Here is my C code to run the recursive assembly file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h> // Include for int32_t

// Declaration of the assembly function using int32_t
extern int32_t meaning_of_life(int32_t n);

int main() {
    int32_t n, result;

    // Prompt the user for input
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n); // Use %d for int32_t as well, it's typically fine for most platforms

    // Call the assembly function
    result = meaning_of_life(n);

    // Print the result
    printf("The result of adding 42 to the number %d times is: %d\n", n, result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `ld a0, 0(sp)` obviously overwrites your result. Also the `li t0, 42` should really be directly before the `add a0, a0, t0` (even if it happens to work in this case).

Comment: You don't need `t0` at all. `addi a0, a0, 42` is a valid instruction: RISC-V immediates are 12-bit sign-extended so `42` fits.

Answer (score 2):

The return value is in `a0`. It returns the input because you explicitly told it to:

```
ld a0, 0(sp)         # Optionally restore original n, if needed for other logic
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we need to preserve the original value incoming in `a` registers for our function's own uses internal to its body, and we might do that saving in the stack.

But we never restore `a` or `t` registers in epilogue for the benefit of callers — they don't expect that so wouldn't take advantage of that (modulo custom calling convention).

Your code doesn't need `n` after the recursive call, so it is pointless to save `a0` in prologue.

As already pointed out, by the standard calling convention, there's no expectation that `t0` will survive a function call, and since it is loaded with a constant, the best approach (from a register perspective) is to simply delay that until later after the function call (yes though, it will fit as an immediate so doesn't even need a register).  In your case the `t0` register will always have 42 because that register is not otherwise used, but relying on this is indeed a violation of the standard calling convention.

---

You should consider writing up a C version of the function `int meaning_of_life(int);`.  Often it is easier to see why things work they way they should in high level language, and, also to see that we're actually doing exactly what is necessary in assembly, nothing less and nothing more.

You can start live variable analysis from the C code to determine which variables are live across a call vs. which are not, and it can be useful to see in that the high level language form before taking to assembly.

```
int meaning_of_life ( int n ) {
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;
    return meaning_of_life ( n-1 ) + 42;
}
```

Here you can see that `n` is not live across a call, so doesn't require special attention or storage.  Once the function call is made, `n` is no longer referenced, only the return value of the function call is further used, by the addition.

However, you're doing something more like this:

```
int meaning_of_life ( int n ) {
    if ( n == 0 ) return 0;
    int x = 42;
    return meaning_of_life ( n-1 ) + x;
}
```

Now a naïve yet correct analysis of this says that `x` ***is*** live across a function call, because it is *defined* before the function call, yet *used* after, so the def/use spans a function call, and thus `x` requires special attention for storage, which could be stack memory or an `s` register (note that `s` registers have their own rules to follow for proper usage).

(The addition cannot happen until both its operands are available, so the function call must be made before the addition can happen, and that makes `x`, used as the 2nd operand of the addition, live across that call to obtain the first operand.)

But it would be silly to store 42 in memory only to reload it later, when it can better be regenerated instead of reloaded.